# How to set the auth.user.id as the default value for a field in a SQLFORM

Tags: python, web2py

I'm having some issues referencing auth_user from other db fields though.  In the following view (company.html) I have a SQLFORM for the 'company' table.  How do I set the user_id field of the company form to default to whatever the current logged in user's ID is?  I tried adding a field called user_id to the company table, but for some reason it causes the form to invalidate every time.

I have the following code within the models folder in another file called db_tasks.py:

```
# Define company table
db.define_table('company',
Field('company_name', notnull=True, unique=True),
Field('user_id', db.auth_user, default=auth.user_id),
Field('email'),
Field('phone', notnull=True),
Field('url'),
format = '%(company_name)s')
```

And an my regular db.py file:

```
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite',pool_size=1,check_reserved=['all'])
auth = Auth(db)

# Add extra user fields
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user'] = [
  Field('address'),
  Field('city'),
  Field('zip'),
  Field('image', 'upload'),
]
```

The controller for company.  When I navigate to this view the User field shows up in the data grid, but not in the forms.  (And I don't want it to, I just want it to be set to whatever user is logged in, i.e. auth.user).  For whatever reason the form won't validate.  I think it has something to do with the model.

```
@auth.requires_login()
def company():
# init a form object for 'company' table
company_form = SQLFORM(db.company).process()
# init a grid object for 'company' table
grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.company, create=False, deletable=False, editable=False, maxtextlength=50, orderby=db.company.company_name)
return locals()
```

Here's the view for company:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<h2>Add a new company:</h2>
<br/>

{{=company_form.custom.begin}}
<strong>Company Name</strong>         <br/>{{=company_form.custom.widget.company_name}}<br/>
 <strong>Email</strong><br/>{{=company_form.custom.widget.email}}<br/>
 <strong>Phone</strong><br/>{{=company_form.custom.widget.phone}}<br/>
 <strong>URL</strong><br/>{{=company_form.custom.widget.url}}<br/>
 {{=company_form.custom.submit}}
 {{=company_form.custom.end}}

 <br/>
 <br/>
 <h2>All Companies:</h2>
 <br/>
 {{=grid}}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about "`session.auth.user.id if session.auth else None`"?

Comment: Figured it out.  Writable field in db_taks.py has to be False for some reason.  Thanks though